# How to get my UIPageViewController to load the correct index? Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipageviewcontroller

This is my first post, so I am open to feedback if I can improve my question.

I have been studying Swift for about a year now and I am trying to build an app that uses UIPageViewController to make an app that mimics the experience of a book. The user is able to create as many pages as they want. For now, I have a template UIViewController with an imageView and a textView. The user presses a "+" button to add the next page, which should appear as a pre-set blank imageView (that they can set) and a blank textView.

Specs:
I'm persisting user information with CoreData.

**The problem:**
I create a new set of pages. Then I add an image and some text. I tap "+" and do the same on the next page. When I tap "+" after that, the next page and each page after that copies the image and text from the previous page rather than being an empty page.

Here is the logic for how my pages should be run.

```
extension BookPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

  func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

      guard let viewControllerIndex = storyPageViewControllers.index(of: viewController as! TemplateViewController) else { return nil }

      if viewControllerIndex == 0 { return nil } // Page won't scroll below first page.

      let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

      guard storyPageViewControllers.count > previousIndex else { return nil }
      currentPage = Double(previousIndex)

      return storyPageViewControllers[previousIndex]
  }

  func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

      guard let viewControllerIndex = storyPageViewControllers.index(of: viewController as! TemplateViewController) else { return nil }

      let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
      let storyPageViewControllersCount = storyPageViewControllers.count

      guard storyPageViewControllersCount != nextIndex else { return nil }

      guard storyPageViewControllersCount > nextIndex else { return nil }
      currentPage = Double(nextIndex)
      return storyPageViewControllers[nextIndex]
  }

  func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
      return storyPageViewControllers.count
  }



  func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
      guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first,
          let firstViewControllerIndex = storyPageViewControllers.index(of: firstViewController as! TemplateViewController) else
      { return 0 }

      return firstViewControllerIndex
  }
}
```

This is the IBAction for "+" button:

```
guard let book = book else { return }
PageController.shared.createPageWith(text: "", pageNumber: currentPage + 1.0, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ImageViewPlaceHolder"), book: book)

updateStoryPageViewControllers()

setViewControllers([storyPageViewControllers[Int(currentPage) + 1]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

UPDATE:
As requested, here are the functions commenters asked for.

```
func updateStoryPageViewControllers() {

    // Mark: - RETURN HERE TO TALK TO SPENCER ABOUT FIXING THE VC UPDATING.

    // Make a check to see which pages already have view controllers, and only make a new view controller for the pages that don't.

    guard let book = book else { return }

    // Create an array of view controllers to store the page VCs being instantiated
    var temporaryViewControllers: [TemplateViewController] = []

    // Loop through the books pages, and make a view controller for each
    if let pages = book.pages?.array as? [Page], pages.count > 0 {
        for page in pages {

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            guard let pageVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TemplateViewController") as? TemplateViewController else { break }

            pageVC.page = page
            temporaryViewControllers.append(pageVC)
        }
    } else {

        //FIXME: - Default image set here.
        guard let page = PageController.shared.createPageWith(text: "", pageNumber: 0, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ImageViewPlaceHolder"), book: book) else { return }
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        guard let pageVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TemplateViewController") as? TemplateViewController else { return }
        pageVC.page = page

        temporaryViewControllers.append(pageVC)
    }
    // Set the self.storyPageViewControllers array to the array you just made and filled.
    self.storyPageViewControllers = temporaryViewControllers
}
```

Here is the code for the createPageWith method:

```
@discardableResult func createPageWith(text: String, pageNumber: Double, image: UIImage, book: Book) -> Page? {
    //Turns the UIImage into data to be saved in CoreData.
    guard let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) else { return nil }

    let page = Page(text: text, pageNumber: pageNumber, photoData: data, book: book)

    BookController.shared.saveToPersistentStore()

    return page
}
```

Comment: And what does the `updateStoryPageViewControllers()` function do?

Comment: Please add the code for this method `PageController.shared.createPageWith`

Comment: I just updated the post to answer your questions, let me know if you have other questions. Thanks!